# Tipsy +Views Tooltip is not working

Tags: drupal-7, tooltip, drupal-views, tipsy

I want to show Tooltip inside Views UI. I installed following two modules:-

- Tipsy
- Views Tooltip

I have following fields in the Views UI:-
Name[Visible]
Snaps[Visible]

Now add field "Global: Tooltip" inside Views UI. I gave a simple "Hello" in the "Tooltip text".

My requirement is to simply show the hello text as tooltip for snaps inside View.

Tipsy Configuration are as follows:-

[image]

Please let me know what am I doing wrong as tooltip is not being shown.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking "child" under content class and check that your page output (use firebug or whatever) does not place the tooltip content class as a sibling (same level) as the tooltip class.